# Can I merge two Git repositories with similar content, but not sharing any ancestry?

Tags: git, merge

I have two code bases, Code base-1, Code Base-2.

I run the commands ...

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

... in both repositories (directories).

There are code differences between code base-1 and code base-2.

I can't branch them because they already contain differences of about 0.1%.  The filenames are the same but there are some slight edits to the code.

Is there a way to merge the differences between the two repositories?

Edited:

For example, let's say I have the following. This is what I am starting out with. There are slight differences between codebase 1 and 2.

```
[oldest code case] 
code-base-1/ 
code-base-1/.git  [git stuff with already created repo] 
code-base-1/file1 
code-base-1/file2 

code-base-2/ 
code-base-2/.git [git stuff with already created repo] 
code-base-2/file1 
code-base-2/file2
```

Ideally, I could delete code-base-2 because it is a little newer.

How would I merge these code bases, so that I eventually come out with one with the merged files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem might comes from the fact those are two different repository (with a different SHA-1 first node), and not one repo cloned and then modified.
That means a '`git fetch`' is probably not enough.

You could simply use an external tool (external to Git that is) to merge the *content* of CB2 (Code-Base-2) into CB1, like WinMerge as suggested in the question "[Merging in changes from outside a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504969/merging-in-changes-from-outside-a-git-repository/505130#505130)".

The other option would be using some graft technique to complete a fetch: see the question "[Can two identically structured git repos be merged when they have never had any common history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651542/can-two-identically-structured-git-repos-be-merged-when-they-have-never-had-any-c)"

```
$ cd project1
$ git config remote.project2.url /path/to/project2
$ git config remote.project2.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/project2/*'
$ git fetch project
```

Plus modify the graft file (`.git/info/grafts`) to link the commits of project2 to project1.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cd code-base-1
git fetch ../code-base-2 master:code-base-2
git merge code-base-2
```

Comment: This would join two versions of the same project like they were different projects (if they have no common commits of cours).

Answer (score -2):

Create the first repository as you have described.

In the second folder create a *file* called ".git" with the contents:

```
gitdir: <path-to-first-repository>/.git
```

In the second repository you can now run git diff, git add/commit etc. to merge in your changes.

Comment: Could be a little more specific.  For example, let's say I have the following.  This is what I am starting out with.  There are slight differences between codebase 1 and 2.

[oldest code case]
code-base-1/
code-base-1/.git [git stuff with already created repo]
code-base-1/file1
code-base-1/file2

code-base-2/
code-base-2/.git [git stuff with already created repo]
code-base-2/file1
code-base-2/file2

Ideally, I could delete code-base-2 because it is a little newer.

How would I merge these code bases.  So that I eventually come out with one with the merged files.