# Merge 2 Different git Repos

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have two different local git repos. Each is hosted on github as (separate) private repos, with its own set of collaborators / developers. I am the owner of those two github repos.

```
# Repo A, which  is in
~/projects/repo-a
# Repo B, which is in
~/projects/repo-b
```

I have two questions:
 * How do I merge *repo-a* to *repo-b*, and vice versa. Is it possible?
 * If it's possible, can we make *repo-a* collaborators do **not** show up on *repo-b*, and vice versa? The idea is to keep the confidentiality of the repo collaborators.

Thanks.

Comment: With regards to [how to merge 2 git repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories), [it's been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277029/combining-multiple-git-repositories) a [few times before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233933/merging-two-git-repositories).

Comment: And the second part to your question could probably be done by `filter-branch`, modifying the authors on each commit message (which, would be modifying history, and not technically a merge).

Answer (score 0):

Submodules are not the best for frequent commits. In my project I use [git-slave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net), which is a little out of date, but suits all my needs :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out "[How do you merge two git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)". In short: Learn about "submodules" and "subtree merging".

My suggestion: read the git book:

- [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- [subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)

Answer (score -2):

```
$ git remote add repo-a <url a>
$ git remote add repo-b <url b>
$ git fetch repo-a
$ git fetch repo-b
$ git checkout repo-a/master
$ git checkout -b merging-branch
$ git merge repo-b/master
```