# merging two git repos

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I did search all the questions that are similar to mine but still, I am not able to achieve what I wanted to.
Please advice if this is possible:

1. I have publicRepo/master branch
2. I have privateRepo/master branch

I would like to simply take the latest of publicRepo/master and merge with privateRepo/master. But I would like to take everything from publicRepo/master regardless of merge conflicts (similar to what used to be `git pull -s` theirs)

How can this be done, so far I have tried these solutions:

1) [Merge 2 Different git Repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199602/merge-2-different-git-repos) (I end up with 3 way merge and get theirs when there are conflicts)
2) [Merging two Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233933/merging-two-git-repositories)

I also tried:

```
git fetch --all (as I added publicRepo/dev as one of my remotes)

git reset --hard publicRepo/dev

git pull (does a 3 way merge, which I do not want, I want everything from my publicRepo/Master)
```

Comment: Checkout public master, fetch private master, merge private master into public master with `--strategy=ours`. This simply takes the tree of public master and ignores all changes from private master. Do not use `--strategy=recursive -X ours`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `git fetch upstream` after making the `publicRepo` as upstream.

1. Add the remote of public repo:

   > git remote add upstream {publicRepo}
2. Fetch the latest data from upstream public repo, while checkout out in your private repo:

   > git fetch upstream