# How do I "merge" two separate git repositories of the same website without losing commit data?

Tags: git, merge, commit

I have two separate git repositories for the same version of a single website.

```
domain.com-1.0
domain.com-2.0
```

Version 2.0 was completely redone from the ground up.  There is no bridge between the two repositories.  I would now like to merge the two into a single repository, but maintain the separation.

I have already tagged domain.com-1.0 in it's repo and now want to clean the working tree and move domain-2.0 and all it's commit history into 1.0's repo.  Is this possible or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Note: domain.com-1.0 will not be developed on anymore and is "being retired".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141338/git-question-possible-to-merge-two-different-by-equal-repositories/1141557#1141557 could help here.

Comment: Hmmm... something like that MIGHT work.  I'll look into that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this as follows:

1. `git remote add` the foo-2.0 to the foo-1.0 repo
2. `git fetch` the stuff from foo-2.0 to the foo-1.0 repo
3. Fire up `gitk --all` to see the branches and do some proper branch (re)naming.

This should work for simple one-off cases. If you need to do this twice a day, you should think up a way to automate step 3.

Comment: Why would I need to merge any branches?  The two repos are completely separate and I'm just going to keep 2.0 in a tag for reference purposes only.

Comment: Merge branches? You do not merge any branches. However, foo-1.0's master branch is there, and then there will be foo-2.0's remote2/master branch. You will want a local branch for remote2/master... so you will need to give that a new name, or call the old master something else and use master as the name for foo-2.0's master... however you want to name that.