# How do I merge locally a master and a fork in git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, branch, fork

I need to use Active_admin with Formtastic 2 and the main branch doesn't support it yet.

A couple of weeks ago someone made a fork to support Formtastic 2
But then other additions were added to the master branch and were not commited to the fork. And now the fork is outdated with other things, but yet it support Formtastic.

How can I merge both of them locally in my computer using git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest way is to switch to your local formtastic branch, then run `git merge master` to merge the master branch changes in (you may have to deal with conflicts after that):

```
git branch formtastic
git merge master
```

If you want your history to be a little more structured, you can rebase instead:

```
git branch formtastic
git rebase -i master
```

Rebasing will make your history cleaner because the way it works is it takes whatever changes you made in formtastic and caches them, then in merges in new changes from master, then it re-plays your formtastic changes on top. This may take a little more work than simply merging though (and you'll have to look up rebasing to understand how it works).

Either way, once everything is conflict-free, tested, and committed in your branch, then you can go back and merge your changes into master like this:

```
git branch master
git merge formtastic
```

Comment: The problem is that is not a branch, it was forked:
This is the original: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin
This is the fork: https://github.com/mak-it/active_admin/tree/formtastic

Comment: @Zequez, see here for how to merge two different repos:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141338/can-i-merge-two-git-repositories-with-similar-content-but-not-sharing-any-ancest
 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244695/how-to-combine-two-branches-from-two-different-repositories-in-a-single-repositor

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew how to search ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new remote reference to your upstream repo, the upstream repo being the original repo you have forked. See:

- "[Git fork is git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/git-fork-is-git-clone/6286877#6286877)",
- "[What is the difference between origin and upstream in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)".

[image]

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin
```

Then you can fetch/pull from `upstream` and update your own local branch.
The various options are explained in "[How do I clean up my Github fork so I can make clean pull requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103022/6309)".